# Summation and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

Let $\{T_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be the sequence of numbers such that $T_1=5, S_n = \sum_{r=1}^n T_r$ . If $S_{m+n} –S_n –S_m=mn$, find $S_{100}$ and $T_{100}$.

I don't know how to proceed with the given information.
I tried simplifying it but still got stuck. Please help me with it.

Comment: Hint:  use the "recursion" on $S$ to write $S_{n+1}$ in terms of $S_1$ and $S_n$.

Comment: I didn't understand can you elaborate?

Comment: Set $m=1$ in the relation for $S$.  Don't forget that $T_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$.